# Cannot find Ethernet adapter on Mint after a restart

Tags: linux-mint, ethernet

I installed *[Linux Mint](https://linuxmint.com/) 17* and had Ethernet connected during the process.
I shut down the computer and the Ethernet connection vanished.
I recall having this same experience with *[Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/)* too.

If the Linux OS can see the Ethernet connection to install and use it during the install why does it vanish after installation or why can I not easily find it otherwise?

Answer (score -1):

sounds like your settings are not being saved, if you enter the following command

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

You can view your network settings here, and fill the required ethernet settings which will be saved.

it should look something like this

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.1
```