# After shutting down & turning on, laptop doesn't recognize Ethernet cable on Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon-64bit

Tags: linux, linux-mint, ethernet

So after shutting down my laptop and turning it on the day after, Linux Mint 17.2 doesn’t recognize my Ethernet cable connection. I have read a [possible answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/823061/why-no-ethernet-after-shut-down). So my questions are simple:

1. Is the setting of the answer showed in the link above a universal setting for all networks?

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.1
```

2. My output for the `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` file is:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
    auto lo
    iface lo 
    inet loopback
```

Should I change this script for the showed in the first item?

P.S.: On the other hand the wireless connection works flawlessly, and this is the first time that the Ethernet connection fails after 5 months of using Linux Mint without previous issues. (Even after upgrading from 17.1 to 17.2).

**Edit 1:** here is the output of the `ifconfig` command:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:a9:63:f7:30:aa  
      inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::faa9:63ff:fef7:30aa/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:210753 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:161101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:242209461 (242.2 MB)  TX bytes:27087183 (27.0 MB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:13316 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:13316 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1452633 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:1452633 (1.4 MB)
```

**Note**: I've found a temporary fix for this issue, to run the command     `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` and then `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` after this actions the Ethernet starts working fine again until I shut down my laptop. Sorry for answering late but at the moment I have a big workload so I will come back to you in the next 48 hours for the update on the modification of the `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` file and the execution of this command `sudo ifdown --exclude=lo -a && sudo ifup --exclude=lo -a`. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is the setting of the answer showed in the link above a universal setting for all networks?

Nope. That configuration setting is strictly for a static network connection that is on that specific network where the network gateway would be `192.168.0.1`, the subnet would be `192.168.0.x` and you want the address to be `192.168.0.100`.

Before your head spins, those settings are basically, “If you know what they mean, then you have a valid reason to change them.” That said, you then ask this:

> 2. My output for the `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` file is: Should I change this script for the showed in the first item?

Nope. As explained above that would only work for a specific network setup; that other answer is incorrect.

That said, there is something you can aedd to `/etc/network/interfaces` to attempt to solve this problem:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Settings for 'eth0'.
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

While that other answer you mentioned uses `iface eth0 inet static`, but this uses DHCP (`iface eth0 inet dhcp`) instead.  So it’s worth it to try that setting, and then restart networking like this:

```
sudo ifdown --exclude=lo -a && sudo ifup --exclude=lo -a
```

Now that all assumes your Ethernet cable is associated with `eth0` on the system. What I would recommend you do is run a simple `ifconfig` command like this:

```
ifconfig
```

Which would output something like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:17:16:01  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe17:1601/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:272 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:345 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:28361 (28.3 KB)  TX bytes:36815 (36.8 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:e7:29:74  
          inet addr:192.168.56.10  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fee7:2974/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:266 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26141 (26.1 KB)  TX bytes:29246 (29.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:974 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:974 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:148494 (148.4 KB)  TX bytes:148494 (148.4 KB)
```

That output basically means I have two Ethernet connections (`eth0` and `eth1`) as well as a local loopback address (`lo`). Every system should have the `lo` and at least `eth0`. Once you know what your interface adapter ID is, use that in the config I have mention above.